# selenium StaleElementReferenceException happening when SendKeys is called

Tags: javascript, selenium

When it does the send keys, you will see the name of the city show up, and clear out, all from that command. I had the wait's added just to check. Any way to work around that? It doesn't fail, because it finds the field, and then clears it out. It cannot be javascript because I have not left the field, and I have not found any code being called by 'keystroke'.

```
try
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id("city"))));
    var city = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("city"));
    //Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
    city.SendKeys(City);
    //Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
}
catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex)
{
    var city = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("city"));
    City.SendKeys(City);
}
```

City above is a property.

Comment: Can you link the site?

Comment: Unfortunately cannot. It's internal and has pw protection

Comment: What happened when explicit waits were added ? Did the issue disappear ?

Comment: The same thing happens. The bandaid around it is that I am adding that text as the last entry. Luckily only happening on one field. Not sure what I would do for a screen that has multiples.

Answer (score 0):

I usually wait for element to be **visible, active and editable** rather than only for it's existence in the DOM.

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.Id("city"))));
```

See [ExpectedConditions#elementToBeClickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-)  for details.

---

It seems that onchange or oninput event is fired when the field is cleared, and some javascript code modifies this element.
First try this code - wait for the element each time before doing every action on it:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.Id("city")))).clear();
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.Id("city")))).SendKeys(City);
```

---

If it still doesn't work, then use a brute-force method - try a few times in a loop:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.Id("city")))).clear();

for( int i = 5; i >=0; i--){
  try{  
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.Id("city")))).SendKeys(City);
    break;
  }catch( StaleElementReferenceException ex ){
    if( i <= 0 ){
       throw ex;
    }else{
       // swallow the exception, wait some time and try again
       Utils.silentSleep( 500 );
    }
}
```

where Utils.silentSleep is:

```
static void silentSleep( long ms ){
   try{
     Thread.sleep( ms );
   }catch( Exception ex ){
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply.family emergency and just got to trying this now...none of this worked, because it is accepting the data, but at the same time as doing the send keys, it removed them...so in the last instance above, it pasted the values, deleted, pasted, deleted, 5 times...the strangest thing. Thanks.